# How to remove words in a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

here iam trying to remove the words in a column and print only (word) words in bracket in anew column. my data is

```
column A     
john(son)
jasmine(jas)
cathy(ct)
duke(dk)
james(jm)
```

required output must be like

```
columnA          ColumnB
john(son)          son
jasmine(jas)       jas
cathy(ct)          ct
duke(dk)            dk
james(jm)           jm
```

can any one help me out of this thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option: However above options are better, Anyway I got this way...

```
patten = re.compile('.*\((\w+)\).*')
df["column2"] = [re.search(patten,i).group(1) for i in df.column1.values]

        column1 column2
0     john(son)     son
1  jasmine(jas)     jas
2     cathy(ct)      ct
3      duke(dk)      dk
4     james(jm)      jm
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract` with regex pattern `r"\((.*?)\)"`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"columnA":['john(son)', 'jasmine(jas)', 'cathy(ct)', 'duke(dk)', 'james(jm)']})
df["columnB"] = df["columnA"].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)" , expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        columnA columnB
0     john(son)     son
1  jasmine(jas)     jas
2     cathy(ct)      ct
3      duke(dk)      dk
4     james(jm)      jm
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\((.*?)\)',x).group(1))
```

Output:

```
        A          B
0   john(son)      son
1   jasmine(jas)   jas
2   cathy(ct)      ct
3   duke(dk)       dk
4   james(jm)      jm
```

Answer (score 0):

go with [pandorable](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/what-is-pandorable)

```
df['column B']=df['column A'].str.split('(',expand=True)[1].str[:-1]
```